# cover whole google map with a transparent overlay?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have lots of polylines and markers, and use different colours. It makes the maps somewhat unreadable. How can I caover the whole map with e.g. Black overlay of 50% opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-overlay-opacity-control/